# Errors on web page on a mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've got a problem in my html code: http://www.playground.obuh.by/ (Bootstrap with disabled responsive) on small resolutions. the problem is that on some resolutions webpage is looking “smaller” in width so that it had a white area on the right side, for example, look on this screenshot:http://joxi.ru/-3_fU4wyTJDIAupGS2Q or this: http://joxi.ru/mtoNVP3JTJCSfN_a8a0

Comment: Do you have this viewport meta tag? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use that, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your website. The white gap that comes in some of your sections is, because you use the `.container` class on them. They therefore have a fixed width. Give them the `.container-fluid` class instead and everything should look fine.